How can i use the results of a Single<List<Type>> to populate a lazy column? Kotlin, Jetpack Compose
I'm currently working through someone's old code and I'm a little confused. How can I use the code below to populate a lazy column? Each lazyColumn item should display a Title and Description. Any help is much appreciated. The lazy column currently doesn't display anything (featureConfigs = listOf<Feature>() doesn't get populated) but i'm not too sure where i've gone wrong.
ViewModel class:
class FeatureConfigViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val featuresRepository: FeaturesRepository,
private val localFeatureConfigOverrider: LocalFeatureConfigOverrider): ViewModel() {

var featureConfigs = listOf<Feature>()
@Inject lateinit var featureConfig: FeatureConfig


init {
    if (
        JSON_FEATURE_FLAG_DATA_KEY.isNotEmpty()
    ) {
        val jsonData = JSON_FEATURE_FLAG_DATA_KEY
        loadFeatures(jsonData)
    } else {
        loadFeatures()
    }
}


fun loadFeatures() {
    loadFeatures(featuresRepository.getFeatures(JSON_FILE_NAME))
}

fun loadFeatures(jsonData: String) {
    loadFeatures(
        featuresRepository.getFeatures(JSON_FILE_NAME)
            .zipWith(
                featuresRepository.getFeaturesFromJson(jsonData)
            ) { featuresFromFile, featuresFromJson ->
                for (feature in featuresFromFile) {
                    val overrideValue = featuresFromJson[feature.key]
                    if (overrideValue != null) {
                        localFeatureConfigOverrider.put(feature.key, overrideValue)
                    }
                }
                featuresFromFile
            }
    )
}

private fun loadFeatures(featuresSingle: Single<List<Feature>>) {
    val d = featuresSingle.subscribe({ featureList ->
        val features = featureList.toMutableList().sortedBy { it.key }
        featureConfigs = features
    }) { throwable ->
        Logger.e(throwable)
    }
}

companion object {
    private const val JSON_FILE_NAME = "fileName.json"
    const val JSON_FEATURE_FLAG_DATA_KEY = "keyName"
}

}
View snippet with the lazyColumn (I'm hoping to use a list containing the results from the ViewModel to populate the lazy column):
LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier
                .weight(weight = 1f, fill = false)
                .fillMaxSize()) {
                items(items = configs) {
                    LazyColumnDescription(
                        name = it.key,
                        description = it.description,
                    )
                }
            }


I'm unsure what your question is. Assuming configs in the LazyColumn is the list of features, and each Feature has a key and a description property, then all seems to be in order. So what do you want to know? Can you be more specific?

@Leviathan it actually isn't loading anything on the lazy column.. So i imagine i did something wrong somewhere

So what is the problem? Is the list empty? Is the composable not displayed? Or something else?

@Leviathan the list isn't populated so the lazy column doesn't contain anything to display

So where does the empty list come from? And was it already empty there?

@Leviathan at the start of the class i create a new list and try to populate it using the loadFeatures() methods. I think i'm doing something wrong there

Compose only can observe data that has been wrapped in State class.
you should change this code :
var featureConfigs = listOf<Feature>()

to this :
val featureConfigs = MutableStateFlow((listOf<Feature>()))

then you should observe this value in compose by below code:
val configList by featureConfigs.collectAsState()

then your UI can recognize you changes.

Thank you for this! I've just tried it but i'm now getting an error - Type mismatch. Required: MutableStateFlow<List<Feature>> Found: List<Feature>  for this featureConfigs = features line and a few other

try this :
featureConfigs.value  =  features

That resolves the error, thank you. Unfortunately I'm still not getting anything displayed on the lazy column

I don't know what all your loadFeatures overloads are doing, but in general, if you want to observe a list from a ViewModel in a Composable, you can store the List in the ViewModel using mutableStateOf().
I assume that you are having some data class called Feature:
data class Feature(
    val key: Int, val description: String
) 

Then, in your ViewModel, you could use something like below. I would recommend to initialize the featureConfigs list with some values to see whether these get displayed in the LazyColumn. Then you can further track down if the error might be coming from the featuresRepository.
class FeatureConfigViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val featuresRepository: FeaturesRepository,
    private val localFeatureConfigOverrider: LocalFeatureConfigOverrider
): ViewModel() {

    var featureConfigs by mutableStateOf<List<Feature>>(
        listOf(Feature(1, "A"), Feature(2, "B"), Feature(3, "C"))
    )

    fun loadFeatures() {
        featureConfigs = featuresRepository.getFeatures()
    }

}

In your Composable, you can access it as follows:
@Composable
MyComposable(featuresVM: FeatureConfigViewModel = viewModel()) {

    Button(onClick = { featuresVM.loadFeatures() }) {
        Text(text = "LOAD FEATURES")
    }

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(weight = 1f, fill = false)
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        items(items = featuresVM.featureConfigs) {
            //...
        }
    }
}

Now, whenever you assign a new List to the featureConfigs variable in the ViewModel, Jetpack Compose will trigger a recomposition and the LazyColumn will be updated.

the best option would be to define a private mutableStateFlow in the viewModel and update its value inside of featuresSingle.subscribe and expose this MutableStateFlow as stateFlow to the view and in the composable just collect this Flow as a state
class FeatureConfigViewModel () {
     //.....
     private val _featureConfig = MutableStateFlow(emptyList< Feature>)
     val featureConfig = _featureConfig.asStateFlow()

     //.....

    private fun loadFeatures(featuresSingle: Single<List<Feature>>) {
        val d = featuresSingle.subscribe({ featureList ->
             val features = featureList.toMutableList().sortedBy { it.key }
        _featureConfig.emit(features)
        }) { throwable ->
           Logger.e(throwable)
        }
       }
     
}

val configs = viewModel.featureConfig.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier
                .weight(weight = 1f, fill = false)
                .fillMaxSize()) {
                items(items = configs) {
                    LazyColumnDescription(
                        name = it.key,
                        description = it.description,
                    )
                }
            }


Hey, i tried this but i'm getting an error - Suspend function 'emit' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function. Also, is there something i need to do with the variable d? I'm realising it's unused.

You can use tryEmit or the best thing would be using the viewModelScope.launch and inside it fo emit the value to the flow
